# Why do I have two users with uid 0 on my Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal

When I execute following code in terminal:

```
dscl . -list /Users UniqueID
```

The output shows two users with **uid 0**: one named **root**, the other named **newuser**.

But when I execute:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

There is only one user with **uid 0**, i.e. root.

I want to know why the answers of above commands are different, and how I can delete the newuser.

I am using the newest version of Mac OS X.

I found this question when I failed to install parallels desktop trial edition. The error message is:

> 15476. Cannot install Parallels Desktop because there is a non-root user account with the UID 0 in your system (http://kb.parallels.com/cn/122763)

I've already called apple support for help, but they had no solution.

Update:

[image: it se]
[image: ![enter image description here]

It seems that **newuser** runs the processes which root should run. Furthermore, the `ps` command is also run by newuser, but my user name is **xlnwel**

What on earth is this **newuser**?

Update 2:

[image]

I have no idea what I have done yesterday (maybe just reboot the computer), but today these processes are run by **root**. but there are still two users with 0 when I run:

`dscl . -list /Users UniqueID`

Comment: Would you mark my answer as accepted please if it fixes the problem for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting.

There is no strict 1-1 mapping from user name to user id in most of *NIX systems, so technically it's all fine to have a few user names with same UID. The reason why you don't see it in `/etc/passwd` is that the file is used for legacy accounts, and directory services are expected to be the source of truth.

I guess you never created the `newuser`? You must understand that the user is effectively a root backdoor into your system, as anyone having the password can act as UID 0 and have full access to your machine.

I'd check for existence of "newuser" in Users & Groups preference pane. You surely should be able to just remove it with `sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Users/newuser"`. The important part is to figure how that user got into your machine in the first place.

Immediate solution: remove the user using the command above.

Actual fix: reinstall the machine clean and restore your data from backups.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no audit log for directory services, so there's no good answer for this question. It might be anything, from weird installers up to malware.

Comment: You can also delete the user through the Directory Utility. See: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7108801?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your questions in turn:

**1. "... why the answers of above commands are different?"**

The reason the answers from the two commands are different is because they are looking at two different records sets.

The /etc/passwd file is only used by OSX in single user mode, as pointed out at the top of the file:

```
##
# User Database
# 
# Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system is running
# in single-user mode.  At other times this information is provided by
# Open Directory.
#
# See the opendirectoryd(8) man page for additional information about
# Open Directory.
##
```

As Directory Services is used for users and resources (printers, servers) you will most likely have more entries in a Directory Services listing than the number of entries in /etc/passwd file.

**2. "... how I can delete the new user?"**

To delete the user you can use dscl commands as pointed out by Farcaller above:

***a) check the details for the user and group with:***

```
dscacheutil -q user
```

And then:

```
dscacheutil -q group
```

I would also check to see what other users are in the same group that "newuser" is in, what files are in /Users/newuser, and then make decisions based on that information.

***b) If all looks OK, delete the user with:***

```
sudo dscl . delete /Users/newuser
```

This will delete everything under the specified directory. If you want to remove the user's home directory you will need to do this manually with:

```
rm -rf /Users/newuser
```

If the "newuser" was in its own group, I would also look at deleting the group with:

```
sudo dscl . delete /Groups/<<GROUP_NAME_OF_NEWUSER_FROM_A_ABOVE>>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thans for your answer. but i can only mark one answer as accepted, since Farcaller answered first,,, i'm very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that helped me

1. Check list of IDs

> dscl . -list /Users UniqueID

2. change the UID to a not used number with the phrase:

> sudo dscl . -change /Users/newuser UniqueID 0 599

where 599 is unique ID and "newuser" is a second user with 0